get files including spezial chars with cfftp
i have to retrieve images from a FTP server with cfftp.
these images have names that include spezial characters like ä, ö, ü, ß, ...
when i list them with the following code none of the spezial chars are correctly displayed
cfftp(action='open', server='server', username='user', password='pass', connection='ftpConnection', port='21', timeout=30);
cfftp(action='listDir', connection='ftpConnection', directory='/', name='ftpFiles');
writeDump(ftpFiles);
cfftp(action='close', connection='ftpConnection');

original filenames on server are for example: Blakläder_overview.jpg, bläöüßbild.jpg
and when i look at my ftpFiles dump they are shown as: BlaklÃ¤der_overview.jpg, blÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃŸbild.jpg
with filezilla or other ftp clients i get the right names.
i already tried to get any additional encoding attribute for cfftp but haven't found one.
Edit: Adding the JVM Argument rrk mentioned, worked perfectly.

Try adding -Dfile.encoding=utf8 to Coldfusion Administrator JVM Arguments and clear all class files in {cfinstall}\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\cfclasses directory and restart CF service.
